# cannot use PATCH in sailsjs v1.0

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, sails.js

I've sails v1.0 with active blueprints APIs, I want to update a field in my model, so if I make an Ajax call with PUT method it says me:

> debug: Using PUT to update a record is deprecated in Sails 1.0. Use PATCH instead!

but if I use PATCH instead it says:

> Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

my security.js config file is:

```
module.exports.security = {

   cors : {
      allRoutes: true,
      allowOrigins: ["http://localhost", "https://localhost"],
      allowRequestMethods: 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH, PUT',
      allowRequestHeaders: 'content-type',
   }
};
```

Can anyone help me?? regards

Comment: I have same issue!   :(

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an OPTIONS route with response 200.